# How do I change the default toolspath for Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I had Visual Studio 2010 beta 1 installed, and I removed. Now, when I try to crate a project in Visual Studio 2008. I get the error "MSBUildToolsPath is not specified for the ToolsVersion "4.0" defined at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\TOolsVersions\4.0", or the value specified evaluates to the empty string". How do I change the ToolsVersion to "3.5", so it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized I had to delete the registry key under HKLM/Software/Wow6432node/Microsoft.

Answer (score 6):

I had successfully uninstalled VS 2015 and got that error. Only deleting 14.0 key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Wow6432node/Microsoft` helped.

Comment: Same.  For more info, see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/02/26/my-visual-studio-2008-is-broken-after-uninstalling-net-framework-4-0 or http://support.embarcadero.com/article/44610

Answer (score 4):

To be precise :
Delete following registries 
HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Msbuild/ToolVersions/14.0
HKLM/Software/Wow6432node/Microsoft/Msbuild/ToolVersions/14.0

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following registry keys do not exist in the machine:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\4.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersion\4.0